# Can you "change" the data in a view?

Tags: sql-server, alter, sql-view

Our company for years put an & in the customer ID's.  Now we're doing this cloud thing and the &'s are causing problems.

I've got this view that I need to change the '&' to a '_' in the customerID field.

Is there a way to this this?

Thanks,

Onyx

Comment: Are you asking about how to alter the view so it displays the data you want *without* changing the underlying data, or do you want to change the underlying data? Could you post your table structure and view?

Comment: Use parameters and URL encode/decode and the &'s shouldn't be a problem

Comment: You have multiple possible solutions. The `REPLACE()` function when SELECTing the value (suggested below); URLEncoding the values, which preserves the ampersand in the data; or updating the base data with underscores (or whatever value is chosen), then not worrying about it again.

Comment: I decided to copy the view to a table and update the data there.
    
    UPDATE `onyxinvoicesummary` 
    SET    CustomerID = replace([CustomerID], '&', '_')
    WHERE  CustomerID LIKE '%&%';

Not as elegant as I would like but it gets the job done.  Although I would have really like to have this done without me having to touch the process every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following SQL statement replaces the '&' with an underscore '_'...

```
    select replace('A&C','&','_')
```

In your case, you'd have an expression like...

```
    select replace([customerID],'&','_')
```

Answer (score -2):

you CANNOT change the table or data value directly from view because view is a result set from multiple tables. And it is kind of dynamic, which  means you have an option to change the data from specific table first before you could see the changes from the view. Use `Update table Set col = replace (col,'&','_') Where...`

Comment: Two things - (1) We haven't determined if the particular view is, in fact, from multiple tables, and (2) it is possible to update through a multi-table view, as long as all updates are to one table (later SQL Server versions).